# call codei-gniter controller data into wordpress and display in json

Tags: wordpress

I am working on Codeigniter MVC architecture using the database: PHPMyAdmin, I am displaying some data in JSON format taken from DB using controller.
I want this data to be displayed on a WordPress page, so how to call this controller onto WordPress for displaying the data?

Comment: This is not a codeigniter problem, what you want is some kind of wordpress plugin that can read json from a given url. So the Codeigniter tag should be removed.

Comment: Okay. any suggestions, on how to solve this issue @marcogmonteiro

Comment: Worpdress use PHP templates so basically you need to find a way to retrieve codeigniter datas when it's included in an external PHP file. For wordpress templates it depend of the content but this is a good start : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

Use a external API and create your own plugin.
and then display it on new page.
References:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saC-7wTpZ_k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-P183PvRIQ